# How to fix "Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" in my program

Tags: android, mysql, database, database-connection

I am very new to android and I'm trying to make a program that shows you results from a database that I have. So when I type in a first name and the database sends the information of that person to me. However, when I look at the LogCat it says 
 "09-09 22:05:39.544: ERROR/log_tag(8813): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

This is my code:

```
public class PS extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //get the two controls we created earlier, also with the resource reference and the id

    final EditText et_Text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_Text);

    //add new KeyListener Callback (to record key input)
    et_Text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        //function to invoke when a key is pressed
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            //check if there is 
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                //check if the right key was pressed
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    InputStream is = null;
                    String result = "";


                    //the name data to send
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",et_Text.getText().toString()));

                    //http post

                    try{
                            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myIPaddress/sampleDB/testSend.php");
                            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            is = entity.getContent();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    }

                // At this point is should be set, if it isn't, tell user what went wrong
                    if (is != null) {

                    //convert response to string
                    try{
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }

                          is.close();

                            result=sb.toString();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    }

                    //parse json data
                    try{
                            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    Log.i("log_tag","PersonID: "+json_data.getInt("personID")+
                                            ", FirstName: "+json_data.getString("FirstName")+
                                            ", LastName: "+json_data.getString("LastName")+
                                            ", Age: "+json_data.getInt("Age")
                                    );

                    } 

                    }catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());

                    }} else {Log.i("log_tag", "Something went wrong!"//I don't know what to put here);} ;  




                  et_Text.setText("");                            
                                    //and clear the EditText control
                return true;
                } 


                }

            return false;
        }
    }); 

}
}
```

This is my php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
   die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

 mysql_select_db("_usersDB", $con);

 $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE FirstName='".$_REQUEST['name']."'");
 while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $output[]=$e;

 print(json_encode($output));

 mysql_close($con);
 ?>
```

The output it's parsing on is when I input "Eric" then It'll give me personID of 1, FirstName of Eric, LastName of (my last name), and age of 15. I'm not sure if you were asking for that...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it may not be wise to share your database connection details with the rest of the world. Second of all, it's not a great idea to do networking operations on the UI Thread.

Lastly (which is what you want to know), it looks likes the output on the server may be different than what the client is expecting. Can you post the output it is parsing on? I'll revise this answer once you do so.

Comment: Hey posted it on the bottom, but I am not sure if I posted what you were asking for...

Comment: The JSON output that you're parsing.

Comment: Ermm... what would it look like? I'm not exactly sure what a JSON output is defined as.

Comment: Okay how about running the PHP script you posted in the browser and paste the result.

Comment: Are there any PHP errors? Check your log. This is looking like a database issue.

Comment: 09-09 23:43:19.511: ERROR/log_tag(9789): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
That's the only error I see in the LogCat

Comment: Okay, maybe I need to work on my clarity, but I meant your server log for PHP errors.

Comment: Ok, I'm very sorry for not knowing anything (T.T) ... How do I get to server log???

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the server is prepending an XML declaration to the JSON (). You might want to examine the HTTP traffic output by the web server (via logging or wireshark) as a first step to see if the problem lies with the client or the server.